docker container throwing usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running
basically I created a script that should work on aws ecs. I'm deploying it over copilot cli. Here is my Dockerfile.py given below
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.10-slim as build
RUN apt-get update
RUN  python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential gcc
# required for psycopg2
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev 
RUN apt-get install -y gnupg
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -yqq unzip
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -

# RUN apt-get install -y wget xvfb unzip
# Set up the Chrome PPA -> (not sure if needed)
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list

# Update the package list
RUN apt-get update -y

# Set up Chromedriver Environment variables and install chrome
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION 114.0.5735.90
ENV CHROME_VERSION 114.0.5735.90-1
RUN wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/chrome.deb https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_${CHROME_VERSION}_amd64.deb \
    && apt install -y /tmp/chrome.deb \
    && rm /tmp/chrome.deb

ENV CHROMEDRIVER_DIR /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
RUN mkdir $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR

# Download and install Chromedriver
RUN wget -q --continue -P $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip"
RUN unzip $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR/chromedriver* -d $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR

# Put Chromedriver into the PATH
ENV PATH $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR:$PATH

# # set display port to avoid crash
ENV DISPLAY=:99

# env variables for aws
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=*-*-*-*
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=*-*-*-*
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=*-*-*-*

# install selenium
RUN pip install selenium==4.11.2

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt 
RUN  python3.10 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "start_worker.py"]

On the other hand, here is my webdriver settings from the python file:
def set_web_driver_settings() -> webdriver.Chrome:
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    # options.add_argument("--start-maximized") # for the populating twitter and discord script. Activate it before the execute that script.
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
    options.add_argument(
        "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    )

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path="usr/local/bin/chromedriver",
        options=options,
    )  # docker

    return driver

I believe that installing chrome is causing main problem. I don't know what information should I give to you more but that's what it is.
Edit: sharing response from docker is below:
{"error": "Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.\n  (chrome not reachable)\n  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)\nStacktrace:\n#0 0x555555c2d4e3 <unknown>\n#1 0x55555595cc76 <unknown>\n#2 0x555555985d78 <unknown>\n#3 0x555555982029 <unknown>\n#4 0x5555559c0ccc <unknown>\n#5 0x5555559c047f <unknown>\n#6 0x5555559b7de3 <unknown>\n#7 0x55555598d2dd <unknown>\n#8 0x55555598e34e <unknown>\n#9 0x555555bed3e4 <unknown>\n#10 0x555555bf13d7 <unknown>\n#11 0x555555bfbb20 <unknown>\n#12 0x555555bf2023 <unknown>\n#13 0x555555bc01aa <unknown>\n#14 0x555555c166b8 <unknown>\n#15 0x555555c16847 <unknown>\n#16 0x555555c26243 <unknown>\n#17 0x2aaaab7ac134 <unknown>\n", "event": "scraper failed", "level": "error", "timestamp": "2024-04-08 04:47.50"}


Is the selenium official chrome docker image not usable for your use case?

I'm not sure about that. Let me try it but it will be great if you give me a suggestion about where to start

Other people around me use Selenium and I have seen enough to know there are images made for various browsers. Other than that I have no deeper knowledge of how to use it or I'd answer rather than comment.
